# Objective-C integrating C Library and passing String value - ARC Error

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to integrate a 3rd party C library into my project, I've never done this before and experiencing a problem with something that should be so simple, passing a string value to the C function.

Below is my code and the line that is failing generates the following error:

'Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'const char *' is disallowed with ARC'

My Code:

```
NSString *myMapCode = @"GBR H4J.XLL";
double lat = 0.0;
double lng = 0.0;

returnValue = mc2coord(&lat, &lng, "GBR H4J.XLL", 0);  // This works perfectly
returnValue = mc2coord(&lat, &lng, myMapCode, 0);      // This is my Problem code
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Here you pass an `NSString`, not a C string:

```
returnValue = mc2coord(&lat, &lng, myMapCode, 0);
```

If that function expects a C string, you can either change

```
NSString *myMapCode = @"GBR H4J.XLL";
```

to

```
const char *myMapCode = "GBR H4J.XLL";
```

or convert the `NSString` to a C string:

```
NSString *myMapCode = @"GBR H4J.XLL";
returnValue = mc2coord(&lat, &lng, [myMapCode UTF8String], 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mc2coord`function does not take an `NSString` object, but rather a C string, or `const char *`. Above, don't save `myMapCode` as an `NSString` but rather the C string and you will be fine.

Comment: Ahh thanks you for your help, its clear I have a lack of understanding of C so something that I'll have to work on.